# Getting a cursor position value and calling it later

Tags: c#, cursor-position

I am stumped as to how I would go about storing the screen/cursor position and calling it back to the exact pixel after it has finished completing the rest of the function.

I am able to run my code when I click a button, but I want to be able to return the cursor to the position it was in when the button was clicked, so I can loop it from that exact location.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I am writing in C# and using VS2010

Comment: <sigh> winforms? silverlight? wpf? asp.net? console? need more info on  your platform.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for you UI Framework.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad user experience to modify the users cursor, that is why the mouse cursor position is generally exposed as Read-Only information.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Windows Forms (if you are able to use System.Windows.Forms assembly) you can use Position property from Cursor class. It allows you to get and set cursor position.
But is's a bad practice to move cursor from your code.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApplication
{
    class MyClass
    {
        void Go()
        {
            var previousPosition = Cursor.Position;

            // Do smth

            Cursor.Position = previousPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you suggest doing so? I have only been writing in C# for a few months which is why something like this has caught me off guard.

Comment: Why is it bad? It's only got a set space that it moves in, and only runs one one form for a specific purpose.

Comment: You should add System.Windows.Forms assembly, then you can write something like code I added to answer.